# “RDS is currently busy” and I can not log in to the server

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access, windows-server-2016, remote-desktop-services

After 2 users have connected (except myself) to the server with RemoteDesktopServices, then I can not log in until the server restarts.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRn7l.jpg)

It gives the error shown on the screenshot.

Everyone in the office can log in except me.  But when the server is restarted, I can log in too.

What I already tried:

- Task Manager: disconnect other users as admin from another account.
- sfc /scannow on cmd as admin
- `"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client " "   Name: RDGClientTransport "` -> I didn't find anything as that name

Comment: Sounds like you have 2 free client license for RDP/TS depleted. Make sure that users always _log off_ TS sessions rather than disconnecting them by red `×`

Comment: I can not login even if they all log off their sessions... Then it's like I am completely out of the system @JosefZ

Comment: Even if the users leave the remote server, I can not log in still

Comment: Hum, I'd try `mstsc /admin` and powerful `arp -d *`.

Comment: @JosefZ I was thinking that command "mstsc /admin" but don't remember did I try this...  what arp -d * command does? and when I should apply this commands during log in error?

Comment: Apply `arp -d *` from an elevated `cmd` window; it should resolve most of dead-lock states (including `mstsc`-related ones) that come from _Address Resolution Protocol_ cache table. Inspect `arp /?` for more details.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will apply it on the server cmd w/ admin level right? BTW I see arp commands with arp /? but arp -d * cmd is deleting all of it, 1- What does this command delete? 2- Is it safe? What does this have to do with RDS? @JosefZ